Reinstate custom event handlers after SocketIO re-connects
I have a VueJS App, with a SocketIO client that connects to a NodeJS Express App, with a SocketIO Server.
The VueJS app makes the socket object returned from socket = io() available as an app-wide variable using app.provide('$socket', socket).
We have several widgets in the VueJS app that users can configure to build out their own event-driven applications. Each of the widgets has a this.$socket.on('msg-input:<widget-id>') event handler that is registered when the component is mounted.
When the server sends a msg-input event, these handlers operate as expected.
However, when the SocketIO client is disconnected for any particular reason and reconnects, none of the custom client-side socket.on event handlers that are defined in the mounted() of the components are fired anymore.
I have verified that the events from the server are successfully being sent. If I add a socket.onAny to the client inside the same mounted handler, they're being picked up successfully, but there is nothing reinstating the custom event handlers?
I had assumed this was auto-handled by SocketIO, but I fear I'm mistaken?
Updates:
After @EstusFlask mentioned it probably isn't linked to Vue, and getting reassurance that SocketIO shouldn't be clearing the handlers, I went digging a little further into my architecture to rule that out, and found that not all custom events are being cleared. Only custom events registered inside a widget are, we have some other higher-level custom handlers that live in our App.vue that are persisting the reconnect().
As such, I then looked at how our widgets are being rendered and at exactly what point the listener is lost, and it's linked to how the widget/page configuration is sent to us. We have a ui-config event which details all the widgets that the user has defined, this include a string to say which "type" of widget it is. Our widgets are then rendered with:
<component :is="w.component" :id="w.id" :props="w.props" :state="w.state"/>

The widget.component property is updated on each of these ui-config events, and in the $nextTick() after this, the widget event handlers are gone.
So, Vue appears to re-render the component but lose the handlers that were created in the mounted as an update to the is="" doesn't re-trigger the mounted handlers

Confirming that the handler is definitely cleared, as when I run console.log('handlers for msg-input:0318b78e790954f1:', socket.listeners('msg-input:0318b78e790954f1').length) in the onAny handler, the result is 0 after the reconnect, but 1 before

This doesn't look specific to Vue, you should be able to reproduce this with plain use of socket which would make the reproduction simpler. This isn't normal behaviour afaik. You could start investigating by debugging removeAllListeners method

Thanks @EstusFlask - having dug in a little more, I'm fairly I've narrowed it down to being a Me/Vue problem.
Any custom event handlers registered outside of a widget persist, the handlers inside a widgets themselves do not. Will update the primary question with extra details
